# Is there any function which can multiply the combination of numbers and then add them?

Tags: combinatorics

> Is there any function which can multiply the combination of numbers and then add them?

For example consider the function which I made, $$C_2(5,6,7)=5 × 6+6 × 7+5 × 7=107$$ or $$C_3(1,2,3,4)=1 × 2 × 3+2 × 3 × 4+4 × 1 × 2+3 × 1 × 4=60.$$

Hope you get it.

Is there any formal notation which is used by everyone?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define it with better notation?

Comment: Yes.. any formal notation which is used by everyone.. Or.. DID I JUST INVENT NEW MATHS??

Comment: These are special cases of *elementary symmetric polynomials*, a topic that is important in advanced algebra.

Answer (score 2):

What about this one?
$$C_3(a,b,c,d)=abcd\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c+\frac1d\right)$$

or even more compact:

$$C_{n-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\prod_{k=1}^nx_k\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{x_k}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is called *[elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)*. Those are extremely useful devices to relate the roots and the coefficients of a polynomial.

For instance, if $a$ and $b$ are the roots of a monic polynomial of degree $2$, then its coefficients are (up to sign) $a+b$ and $ab$, namely $C_1(a,b)$ and $C_2(a,b)$:

$$(X-a)(X-b)=X^2-(a+b)X+ab$$

The common notation for your $C_i$ is in fact $e_i$ - you were quite close!

Comment: Thanks.. I chose C because it stood for combination

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $\binom{S}{k}$ the set of $k$-element subsets chosen from $S$. Then your function is

$$ C_m(S) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{T \subset \binom{S}{m} } \prod_{t \in T} x_t $$

where $S =\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

How about $$c_x(\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\})=\sum_{\substack{I\subset\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\};\\|I|=x}} \prod_{i \in I}i \phantom{¯\_(ツ)_/¯}?$$